# How to give custom classes to the WordPress Menu widget

Tags: menus, widgets

I have created a custom menu widget, which is, in fact, a replica of the default widget provided by the core WordPress files.

But I am facing few challenges it is not able to accommodate my custom menu, classes.

I checked the page into the browser and it is rendering this kind of HTML →

I have received some answer that is about to solve my problem. So, in short, I am bit educated now than before. The issue is this →
If I use this →`'menu_class'  => 'footer-menu'` then it is injecting new class in the `<ul></ul>` tag, but that is not wanted. I want to inject my class in the `div` tag.

Currently, this structure is coming →
`<div class="menu-menu-1-container"><ul id="menu-menu-3" class="menu"><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-4"><a href="http://codepen.trafficopedia.com/site01/">Home</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-26"><a href="http://codepen.trafficopedia.com/site01/">Menu 1</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-27"><a href="http://codepen.trafficopedia.com/site01/">Menu 2</a></li>
<li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-28"><a href="http://codepen.trafficopedia.com/site01/">Menu 3</a></li>
</ul></div>`

---

But I want it like this →

`<nav class="footer-menu">
    <ul id="menu-menu-3" class="menu"><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-4">
        <a href="http://codepen.trafficopedia.com/site01/">Home</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-26"><a href="http://codepen.trafficopedia.com/site01/">Menu 1</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-27"><a href="http://codepen.trafficopedia.com/site01/">Menu 2</a></li>
        <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-28"><a href="http://codepen.trafficopedia.com/site01/">Menu 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>`

So I think if somehow I can inject a `new class` in the container parameter + change its structure from div to nav then everything seems to be fixed.

[The Live WP Link](http://codepen.trafficopedia.com/site01/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Updated based on comments below.)

`<div class="menu-menu-1-container">` is coming from WP's default menu container. You can customize what tag is used (div, ul, etc.) or tell WP not to use a container at all, as well as set the ID and/or class (menu-menu-1-container, etc.) by using the `container`, `container_class` and `container_id` arguments when you call `wp_nav_menu`.

`<ul id="menu-menu-4" class="menu">` - you can easily change this class and ID by including `menu_class` and `menu_id` when you call the menu, toward the end of your "Front End display" block:

```
$nav_menu_args = array(
    'fallback_cb' => '',
    'container' => 'ul',
    'container_class' => 'my_custom_container_class',
    'container_id' => 'my_custom_container_id',
    'menu' => $nav_menu,
    'menu_class' => 'my_custom_css_class',
    'menu_id' => 'my_custom_css_id'
);
```

Change class and ID to whatever you like, variables or whatever. Make sure if you'll be displaying multiple menus on a single URL you set the ID to a dynamic variable so you don't have multiple menus with the same ID.

If you need to customize anything further, [WP's code reference on wp_nav_menu](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) lists everything you can tweak. If even that is not enough, consider looking into a custom walker.

Comment: You can change the wrapping `div` and its class with the `container` parameter in `$nav_menu_args`.

Comment: @cjbj Just like 'menu_class' => 'my_custom_css_class',? Can you guide me who, and what parameters will be used in doing so?

Comment: @WebElaine → <div class="menu-menu-1-container"> is coming from somewhere else. You need to track it down within your theme to change it.
_____________

This is coming nowhere from my class but from some default WordPress core. I think this can be disabled. I watched some video on tutsplus.com a few months back, but could not recall from where in those videos they were educating how to disable these classes by putting something to false.

Comment: @WebElaine I tried this class → 'menu_class' => 'footer-menu',   and the CSS is imposed in the < ul> tag. [Click Here](https://www.screencast.com/t/xT3YqmDl). There should be some method to eliminate(or putting to false) this from the </div> → menu-menu-1-container

Comment: Finally it looks like that I have solved it →
    'container'   => 'nav',
                'container_class' => 'footer-menu'

Comment: @WebElaine, Please update your answer a little bit with two more parameters so that it will be useful to the future visitors then I can accept your answer. Your help was incredible.

Comment: @WP Novice, glad I could point you in the right direction. The answer is updated with all the comment info.